# Purpose of square brackets in shell scripts

Tags: unix, sh

I came across this line in one of the shell scripts:

```
[-f $host_something ] && .$host_something
```

What are the square brackets with the `-f` switch supposed to do, and what is the point of ANDing it with the same environment variable?

Comment: I think you are missing some spaces - one after the `[`, and one after the `.` ... these are important; the command won't work without them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[` is actually an actual binary. It's an alias for the `test(1)` command. It will ignore it's last argument which should be `]`. Run `man test` for further information. It's not really shell syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The square bracket is really an alias for the `test` tool, so you can look at `man test` to find out how it works. the `-f` switch is one of many tests that can be run by this tool, and tests if a file exists and is a regular file.

Answer (score 2):

You need some more spaces.
The command

```
[ -f $host_something ] && . $host_something
```

stands for

```
if [ -f $host_something ]; then
   source $host_something
fi
```

or in words:
When the file given in the variable `host_something` really is a file, then execute the lines in that file without opening a subshell. You do not want a subshell, since all the settings in the subshell get lost as soon as the subshell is finished.